# automatically prefill zip code when user starts entering address

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How do I add the zip code? It finds everything I need except the only thing I cant figure out is how to add the zip code to automatically prefill when the user starts typing there address in.

http://jsfiddle.net/DXkZJ/1/

```js
     $(function () {
         var lat = 44.88623409320778,
             lng = -87.86480712897173,
             latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
             image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';

         //zoomControl: true,
         //zoomControlOptions: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,

         var mapOptions = {
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
             zoom: 13,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
             panControl: true,
             panControlOptions: {
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
             },
             zoomControl: true,
             zoomControlOptions: {
                 style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
             }
         },
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: latlng,
                 map: map,
                 icon: image
             });

         var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
         var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
             types: ["geocode"]
         });

         autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

         google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
             infowindow.close();
             var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
             if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                 map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
             } else {
                 map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                 map.setZoom(17);
             }

             moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
             $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
             $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
         });
         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
             $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
             $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
             infowindow.close();
                     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                     geocoder.geocode({
                         "latLng":event.latLng
                     }, function (results, status) {
                         console.log(results, status);
                         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                             console.log(results);
                             var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                 lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                                 placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                                 latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                             moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                             $("#searchTextField").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                         }
                     });
         });
        
         function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
             marker.setIcon(image);
             marker.setPosition(latlng);
             infowindow.setContent(placeName);
             //infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=uk&language=en&sensor=true"></script>

Address:
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" style="text-align: left;width:357px;direction: ltr;">
<br>
            latitude:<input name="latitude" class="MapLat" value="" type="text" placeholder="Latitude" style="width: 161px;" disabled>
            longitude:<input name="longitude" class="MapLon" value="" type="text" placeholder="Longitude" style="width: 161px;" disabled>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 350px;width: 500px;margin: 0.6em;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at the `fillInAddress()` method of this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform). Among other details, it will update the `postal_code` input field in the document.

Probably most relevant is this `if` statement inside the `fillInAddress()` for-loop:

```
if (componentForm[addressType]) {
  var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
  document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
}
```

When `place.address_components[i]` is equal to "postal_code," it will go ahead and place the value of `place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]]` in a var called `val`. This will return the `short_name` of the postal code.